# How to grant access to storage.buckets.list in GCP Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, roles, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have create a new Firestore project and want to be able to create, update and delete but simply trying to list buckets gives me the following error:

```
<user>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud projec
```

In GCP When searching filtering roles, there doesn't appear to be specific storage or bucket roles. Similarly the only firestore role is `Firestore Service Agent` but can't see how to apply it.

I think I am confused by IAM, Principles, roles. Looks like IAM has permissions and roles attached to it and a principle is another name for the user?

Either way, how can I apply the correct roles and permissions to my service account credentials so that I can list buckets?

EDIT:
Screenshot [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want your service account to have full access to the bucket(s), you can give it the IAM role `Storage Admin`. IAM roles actually include a bunch of permissions, in this case, it includes `storage.buckets.list` and many other permissions.

If you want more restriction on the service account permissions, you could give it some other roles defined here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles. For instance, if the service account only has to read information in buckets, you could give it the role `Storage Object Viewer`.

Another way to do it would be to give your service account role(s) directly in each bucket instead of defining the role in IAM. This way, you can give a service account access to a single bucket instead of giving it access to all the project's buckets.

Comment: So if I want the service account to have full access, how do I do that? When I try add permissions, I can't seem to see iam roles for storage.buckets.list or anything similar? (added screenshot to original post)

Comment: To add a role to a service account, go to IAM menu instead of the service account menu (select the first item in the left menu). If your service account is already listed use the pencil icon to edit it's roles and add the role `Storage Admin`. If it's not in the list, use the `Add` option to add it and then give it the role `Storage Admin`. Again, the role includes permissions, so if a service account has the role `Storage Admin`, it will have the permission `storage.buckets.list` and many other permissions.